# Python function for Count of date of month number within a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Edited to add payload example and complete script
Edited again to modify the script and format my problem better

I am creating a script to analyse payment cycles from a bank statement of multiple payments. I am working out the most frequent day of week and date of month and selecting the highest as either day of week along with its position and frequency of payments within a given month or a specific date.

Where its a specific date, I expect the second and third highest dates to be either side of where the highest used date falls on a weekend or on a public holiday.

I created a function to do a count of the days in a week without needing to sort the dataframe and to allow me to add that value as a column in the dataframe rather than it ending up as a list.

**What I need help on?**

That was fine for working through 7 days and counting based on filters but, when doing it by the date of the month, my function for it has 31 if statements. How can I make this more concise and gain the same outcome?

Also, I have the problem with:
`SettingWithCopyWarning:  A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame. Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead` which I simply can't get to go away. Copy vs View, I really don't mind whether it uses a copy or view, I just want to get rid of the warming one way or the other.

**Script and Example Data**

Below is the part of the script I need to make tidier:

```
# function to filter by date of month to perform a count of each

import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\mattl\OneDrive\Desktop\netflix - only.csv")

# Convert to a Date format here
df['new_date']=df['date'].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%d/%m/%Y'))

# Extend data frame with month, day of month and week day
df['month'] = df['new_date'].apply(lambda x: x.month)
df['dom'] = df['new_date'].apply(lambda x: x.day)
df['dow']=df['new_date'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime("%A"))

# function to filter by weekday to perform a count of each
def totalForWeekDay(weekDay):
    filter = df.dow.value_counts();
    #print(filter);
    if weekDay == 'Sunday':
        return filter['Sunday'];
    if weekDay == 'Monday':
        return filter['Monday'];
    if weekDay == 'Tuesday':
        return filter['Tuesday'];
    if weekDay == 'Wednesday':
        return filter['Wednesday'];
    if weekDay == 'Thursday':
        return filter['Thursday'];
    if weekDay == 'Friday':
        return filter['Friday'];
    if weekDay == 'Saturday':
        return filter['Saturday'];

# function to filter by date of month to perform a count of each
def totalForMonthDate(monthDay):
    filter = df.dom.value_counts();
    #print(filter);
    if monthDay == 31:
        return filter[31];
    if monthDay == 30:
        return filter[30];
    if monthDay == 29:
        return filter[29];
    if monthDay == 28:
        return filter[28];
    if monthDay == 27:
        return filter[27];
    if monthDay == 26:
        return filter[26];
    if monthDay == 25:
        return filter[25];
    if monthDay == 24:
        return filter[24];
    if monthDay == 23:
        return filter[23];
    if monthDay == 22:
        return filter[22];
    if monthDay == 21:
        return filter[21];
    if monthDay == 20:
        return filter[20];
    if monthDay == 19:
        return filter[19];
    if monthDay == 18:
        return filter[18];
    if monthDay == 17:
        return filter[17];
    if monthDay == 16:
        return filter[16];
    if monthDay == 15:
        return filter[15];
    if monthDay == 14:
        return filter[14];
    if monthDay == 13:
        return filter[13];
    if monthDay == 12:
        return filter[12];
    if monthDay == 11:
        return filter[11];
    if monthDay == 10:
        return filter[10];
    if monthDay == 9:
        return filter[9];
    if monthDay == 8:
        return filter[8];
    if monthDay == 7:
        return filter[7];
    if monthDay == 6:
        return filter[6];
    if monthDay == 5:
        return filter[5];
    if monthDay == 4:
        return filter[4];
    if monthDay == 3:
        return filter[3];
    if monthDay == 2:
        return filter[2];
    if monthDay == 1:
        return filter[1];

# Add column which calls the function resulting it total count of week_day
df['dow_total'] = df['dow'].apply(lambda row: totalForWeekDay(row));

# Add formula and column to dataframe which counts the month number
df['dom_total'] = df['dom'].apply(lambda row: totalForMonthDate(row));

# Show results
print(df)

if df["dom_total"].max() >= df["dow_total"].max():
    # Determine the top day of month result
    top_dom_tot = df.loc[df['dom_total'] == df['dom_total'].max()]

    # isolate the top day of month
    top_day_of_month = (top_dom_tot['dom'][0])
    print('Top day of month is:')
    print(top_day_of_month)

    # find dates in list where the date of month is NOT the highest number
    dfa = df.loc[df['dom'] != top_day_of_month]

    # Determine number of days forwards (positive) or back (negative)
    dfa['days_diff'] = df['dom'] - top_day_of_month
    print('Payments that are not related to the top day per month')
    print(dfa)
```

Now for the example csv payload:

```
type,party,date, debit , credit 
payment,Netflix,22/01/2021,-$19.99, $-   
payment,Netflix,22/02/2021,-$19.99, $-   
payment,Netflix,22/03/2021,-$19.99, $-   
payment,Netflix,22/04/2021,-$19.99, $-   
payment,Netflix,24/05/2021,-$19.99, $-   
payment,Netflix,22/06/2021,-$19.99, $-   
payment,Netflix,22/07/2021,-$19.99, $-   
payment,Netflix,23/08/2021,-$19.99, $-   
payment,Netflix,22/09/2021,-$19.99, $-   
payment,Netflix,22/10/2021,-$19.99, $-
```

Thanks for your advice!

Comment: `dom` is from date using this `df['dom'] = df['new_date'].apply(lambda x: x.day)` - forgot to include it above

Comment: you could likely simplify the function as `return filter[monthDay]`

Comment: Please provide an example dataset

Comment: I get from your question you are trying to identify the day of week and numeric day of month for which payments are made.  What I don't understand is your statement "selecting the highest as either day of week along with its position and frequency of payments within a given month or a specific date."  Can you please clarify what your want?

Comment: @itprorh66 sure, so some customers or suppliers base their cycle on a specific date (22nd of the month) and some will by a day of week (last Friday of the month). Where it is a specific date, it can change if the specific date falls on a Saturday or Sunday. With exception to salary (where you might choose to pay employees on an earlier date), most people would pay their bill or invoice on the next available weekday. So, if 22nd falls on a Saturday of a given month, the payment cycle this time will be the Monday 24th.

Comment: @mozway I've edited the post to include the full script and an example payload

Comment: Take a look at the pandas timestamp methods to assist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In `totalForMonthDate()`, you can replace this series of if statements with two lines:

   ```py
   def totalForMonthDate(monthDay):
       filter = df.dom.value_counts()
       return filter[monthDay]
   ```

   Of course, you're also running value_counts() once for every row in your dataframe, when it's the same for the whole dataframe. That's inefficient. You can replace this by doing value_counts() once and using map to translate the values:

   ```py
   df['dom_total'] = df['dom'].map(df['dom'].value_counts())
   ```

   Not only is this shorter (1 line vs 4 lines) but it's faster too.
2. You're getting a SettingWithCopyWarning because you're using .loc to filter down the dataframe, then modifying that filtered subset. The simplest way to fix this is to throw in a copy when you're subsetting the dataframe.

   ```
   dfa = df.loc[df['dom'] != top_day_of_month].copy()
   ```

   Note: the code afterward which adds a new column won't affect the original dataframe.

Here is the full source code:

```py
import pandas as pd
import io
from datetime import datetime

s = """type,party,date, debit , credit 
payment,Netflix,22/01/2021,-$19.99, $-   
payment,Netflix,22/02/2021,-$19.99, $-   
payment,Netflix,22/03/2021,-$19.99, $-   
payment,Netflix,22/04/2021,-$19.99, $-   
payment,Netflix,24/05/2021,-$19.99, $-   
payment,Netflix,22/06/2021,-$19.99, $-   
payment,Netflix,22/07/2021,-$19.99, $-   
payment,Netflix,23/08/2021,-$19.99, $-   
payment,Netflix,22/09/2021,-$19.99, $-   
payment,Netflix,22/10/2021,-$19.99, $-   """

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s))

# Convert to a Date format here
df['new_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%d/%m/%Y')

# Extend data frame with month, day of month and week day
df['month'] = df['new_date'].dt.month
df['dom'] = df['new_date'].dt.day
df['dow'] = df['new_date'].dt.strftime("%A")

# Add column which calls the function resulting it total count of week_day
df['dow_total'] = df['dow'].map(df['dow'].value_counts())

# Add formula and column to dataframe which counts the month number
df['dom_total'] = df['dom'].map(df['dom'].value_counts())

# Show results
print(df)

if df["dom_total"].max() >= df["dow_total"].max():
    # Determine the top day of month result
    top_dom_tot = df.loc[df['dom_total'] == df['dom_total'].max()]

    # isolate the top day of month
    top_day_of_month = (top_dom_tot['dom'][0])
    print('Top day of month is:')
    print(top_day_of_month)

    # find dates in list where the date of month is NOT the highest number
    dfa = df.loc[df['dom'] != top_day_of_month].copy()

    # Determine number of days forwards (positive) or back (negative)
    dfa['days_diff'] = df['dom'] - top_day_of_month
    print('Payments that are not related to the top day per month')
    print(dfa)
```

Anyways, hope that helped. Cool project!

Comment: this is awesome, thanks so much :) I'll try it out now